# Codewars Coding Meetup #6 - Can they code in the same language?

Tags: javascript

I'm starting very basic trying to approach this using for and if loops, rather than anything too advanced for myself. I am seeking a push in the right direction.

> You will be given an array of objects (associative arrays in PHP)
>   representing data about developers who have signed up to attend the
>   next coding meetup that you are organising.
>
> Your task is to return either:
>
> true if all developers in the list code in the same language; or false
>   otherwise. For example, given the following input array:
>
> ```
> var list1 = [
>   { firstName: 'Daniel', lastName: 'J.', country: 'Aruba', continent: 'Americas', age: 42, language: 'JavaScript' },
>   { firstName: 'Kseniya', lastName: 'T.', country: 'Belarus', continent: 'Europe', age: 22, language: 'JavaScript' },
>   { firstName: 'Hanna', lastName: 'L.', country: 'Hungary', continent: 'Europe', age: 65, language: 'JavaScript' },
> ];
> ```
>
> your function should return true.

My logic is that if every language in the array is equal to the very first one, then it should return true, as clearly they would all be the same, if not return false.

However when I run the code it returns only true and fails to return false, here is what I have:

```
function isSameLanguage(list) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].language === list[0].language) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: The first time through `i` is 0, so it will return true and exit the function...

Comment: ahhh! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the simple language your codes means

```
if (list[i].language === list[0].language) {
  return true;
}
```

The above part means that if `list[i].language`(any language) is equal to first element's language `list[0].language`  then return `true`. So this is not what you want.

You want if any of the language `list[i].language` is not equal to first language `list[0].language` then return `false`

You should change condition from `===` to `!==` and then return false inside the loop

```js
var list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Daniel', lastName: 'J.', country: 'Aruba', continent: 'Americas', age: 42, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Kseniya', lastName: 'T.', country: 'Belarus', continent: 'Europe', age: 22, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Hanna', lastName: 'L.', country: 'Hungary', continent: 'Europe', age: 65, language: 'JavaScript' },
];

function isSameLanguage(list) {
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++){
    if (list[i].language !== list[0].language){
    return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(isSameLanguage(list1))
```

Comment: Thank you Maheer it's worked, I feel ridiculous! Can I why has that worked? Why did that make a difference I really don't understand?

Comment: @CocoFlade I added a kind of explanation. If you need more I am here for you. I really appreciate that people ask for the reason of code.

Comment: You've added a perfect explanation I cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your logic is that it will return `true` as soon as it find a language that is similar to the 1st item. In addition, you start the iteration from the 1st item, which is identical to itself.

An easier option would be to use `Array.every()`, and check all items vs the 1st item. If any of them doesn't have a matching language, the function would return `false`.

```js
const list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Daniel', lastName: 'J.', country: 'Aruba', continent: 'Americas', age: 42, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Kseniya', lastName: 'T.', country: 'Belarus', continent: 'Europe', age: 22, language: 'JavaScript' },
  { firstName: 'Hanna', lastName: 'L.', country: 'Hungary', continent: 'Europe', age: 65, language: 'JavaScript' },
];

function isSameLanguage([start, ...rest]) {
  return rest.every(o => o.language === start.language);
}
console.log(isSameLanguage(list1))
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a look at Array.every() earlier today but the way you have written your code blew my mind so I had to take a step back. But again thank you for taking your time out to help me.